# Smashing stack error with x86_64 asm code with arithmetic operations on arrays

Tags: arrays, c, gdb, x86-64, nasm

I wanted to call my function in assembly language through C language but i have a beautiful
**stack smashing detected: terminated Aborted (core dumped)** error.

It is a function that takes 3 parameters : *the array (RDI), the number of elements in the array (RSI) and the value that multiplies each element of the array (RDX)*.
The multiplication properly works but i still have an error and i don't know why... Could you help me ?

Here is my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mul_tab(int *tab,int length,int value);

int main(void)
{
    int tab[2] = {1,2};
    mul_tab(tab,2,2);
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tab)/4;i++)
    {
        printf("tab[%d] = %d\n",i,tab[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my asm x86_64 code :

```
global mul_tab
section .text
mul_tab:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    mov qword [rbp-0x8],rdi
    mov qword [rbp-0x10],rsi
    mov qword [rbp-0x18],rdx
    mov rdi,[rbp-0x8]
    mov rsi,[rbp-0x10]
    mov rdx,[rbp-0x18]
mul_tab_loop:
    cmp rsi,0x0
    je mul_tab_fin
    mov rax,[rdi]
    mul rdx
    mov rdx,qword [rbp-0x18]
    mov qword [rdi],rax
    add rdi,0x8
    dec rsi
    jmp mul_tab_loop
mul_tab_fin:
    pop rbp
    ret
```

I assemble, compile and link with :

```
nasm -f elf64 include.inc -o include.o
gcc test.c include.o -o include -g
```

Thank you for your attention to this.

Comment: Why is there used add rdi,0x8 instead of add rdi,0x4?

Comment: i used this because i thought that RDI was an 8 bytes address so i used 0x8 instead of 0x4. Is it 0x4 because of the integer ?

Comment: Here you are using the magic number 4 instead of sizeof( int ) for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tab)/4;i++) and the assembler code you are using the magic number 8 You need to add to the register rdi the value of sizeof( int ) that is usually equal to 4.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: the rest of the asm loop is using 64-bit operand-size, like `mov qword [rdi],rax`, i.e. `int64_t` or `long`, not `int`.  The problem isn't just the pointer-increment; changing that without changing the rest would still over-write past the end of the output array.  This asm is weird, starting out like debug-mode compiler output spilling / reloading register args for no reason.